# Есть ли БД, которая может храниться в оперативной памяти или выбранные её таблицы?

Tags: база-данных

Добрый день.

Есть ли БД, которая может храниться в оперативной памяти для быстрого перебора записей, или выбранные её таблицы?
Объём самой базы будет не такой уж и большой (не больше самой оперативной памяти), но обращаться к тем данным планируется часто.

Возможно ли писать тот же самый sql, как и к обычной бд, но чтоб перебирались значения в оперативке?

Спасибо.

Comment: в сумме, судя по вопросам человек пишет чатик. @Роман Ракзин присоединяюсь к коменту выше - опишите суть задачи и вам помогут определиться с реализацией. И да, ИМХО, до высоконагруженности вам далеко - не нужно заниматься переоптимизацией.

Comment: Если ваш объём данных невелик, а скорость обращения важна, нужна ли вам база данных вовсе?

Comment: ну да, не хранить же в опертивке просто так- вдруг сбой, перезапуск - и всё ляпнет

Answer (score 3):

Принимаю ставки на то, сколько очевидных запросов к гуглу мне пришлось сделать, чтобы найти это http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases

И, конечно, отдельно: вместо того, чтобы описать ситуацию и бутылочое горло разом, вы зачем-то в десятый раз спрашиваете советы по конкретной реализации кэширования/быстрого извлечения данных, которые вам из разу в раз не подходят. Исходя из пары моментов, уверен, что они на самом деле ва и не нужны вообще.

Comment: Ну да, тут точно заметили - хочу написать чат. Как я понял, на php это геморройно будет (со всякими демонами так и не разобрался пока, что это такое), а на ноде, по идее, и по нагрузке меньше, и вообще легче. А по поводу быстрого доступа - хочу сделать сайт для тестирования студентов. Подразумевается, что в одно время открывается комната, и сразу человек 200-500 проходят одномоментно тестирование, вот и думаю, как по нагрузке будет. Может и заморачиваюсь с производительностью, но для себя хочу знать возможные варианты реализации.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, чат уже написан. http://socket.io/demos/chat/ . С производительностью все в порядке.

Answer (score 2):

Их много, но я лично как-то прикипел к Hypersonic SQLDB - он же [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) - простой, как автомат Калашникова, и столь же убийственный. Рекомендую.